# How to fire dbclick event on HTML element (like tbody> tr > td) in Chrome's Console? I need to do it by javascript code (for process automation)

Tags: javascript, automation, click, mouseevent, double-click

How to fire dbclick event on HTML element (like tbody> tr > td) in Chrome's Console? I need to do it by javascript code (for process automation)

Let's imagine I have table with tbody > tr > td. How to add doubleClick event and fire it automatically on this html element (by javascript, programatically, automatically, not manually by user/mouse). I need to do it in Chrome in it's console.

Thx for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var target = document.querySelector('td');
target.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
  alert('dblclick')
})

var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent('dblclick', true, true);
target.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>clicked</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```